# Limitations of spring-boot-devtools with a remote application

Tags: spring-boot

In the Spring Boot documentation, it states "The Spring Boot developer tools are not just limited to local development. You can also use several features when running applications remotely.".

My question is whether or not there is a decent place to look for a list of features that are and aren't supported when working remotely, or if they differ in behaviour from their local working counterparts?

For instance, the current behaviour that I see under Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE is that when performing template changes under bootRun locally, the template is live reloaded with no application restart.  However, when using devtools remotely, a template change will trigger a full hot restart.

Without having a definitive list of the supported features of the remote setup, I don't know if this is expected behaviour or misconfiguration on my part.